# I solved this interesting problem using Taylor series expansion, but would like to find a shorter way.

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

$f(x)=\frac{3x-1}{x^2-1}$;
$f_1(x)= \frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ ,
$f_2(x)= \frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x)$,
find  $f_{50}(0)$

---

I was able to solve this question using the Taylor Series Expansion till 50 terms by differentiating it thrice and generalizing the pattern. I was unable to solve it by other shorter methods. The series expansion I got was:-

---

$f(x)=1-3x+x^2-3x^3+x^4.....-3x^{49}+x^{50}$

$f_{50}(x)=50!$

$f_{50}(0)=50!$

Comment: What if you wrote it as $$\dfrac{3x-1}{x^2-1} = \frac{2}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x-1}$$

Comment: Using @Moo's hint, the pattern is just immediate for the Taylor series.

Comment: Thanks @Moo this makes finding the expansion much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. Using $ \frac{1}{1-x^2}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n}$ for $|x|<1$ you will find

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n$$

for $|x|<1$  with $a_0=1$,$a_{2n}=1$ and $a_{2n-1}=-3$  for $ n \in \mathbb N.$

Hence

$$f^{(50)}(0)=f_{50}(0)=50! \cdot a_{50}=50!.$$

Comment: This is perhaps the best method. Thanks.